# getClassLoaderCache error when upgrading Gradle from 6.7 to 7.0.1

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew

I'm fairly new to Gradle. Whenever I try to upgrade an existing project from 6.7 to 7.0.1 a traceback comes up as

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.getClassLoaderCache()
```

Is there any workaround or missing dependency that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and could solve it by upgrading one of my plugins. From

```
 plugins {
     id 'org.gradle.test-retry' version '1.1.3'
 }
```

to

```
 plugins {
     id 'org.gradle.test-retry' version '1.3.1'
 }
```

So perhaps checking your plugins might help. Shame that the Gradle exception doesn't help at all.

Comment: This helped! Wow, and yeah gradle can be quite cryptic at times. Thanks!